# Too many "martial artists". How to cut them down?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

I am editing a tag in [Martial Arts SE](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/). This tag is called "etiquette". Here is what I have written for the "Usage guidance (excerpt)":

> Use this tag for questions about expected behavior, the correct code of conduct for different styles of martial arts, **and communication among martial artists and that between martial artists and non-martial artists.**

As you can see, the last bit in bold is a mess. I think that the general meaning is clear, but the repetition of "martial artists" is quite annoying.

Is there a way I can say the same thing without having to repeat "martial artists"?

Just to make this clear, "communication" here refers to that

- among practitioners (within the group)
- between practitioners and general people (between groups)

Comment: Are you saying that communication is not allowed among people in general? That in order for any kind of discussion to be valid there must be at least one martial artists present in the conversation? Unless that is the case, which I find odd, I would simplify it to just *… and communication about martial arts.*

Comment: @JasonBassford It is for a tag called "etiquette" in Martial Arts SE. So, *martial arts etiquette* is concerned about practitioners (e.g., white belt BJJ practitioners should not ask black belts to roll with them; they must wait for black belts to invite them if black belts wish to do so). So the tag should say that it is about communication among artists, and between artists and general people, but not among general people. So yes, basically the tag is for when we have questions about communication where at least one of the speakers is a practitioner.

Comment: First of all, that sounds awfully elitist. But, that aside, then just say *…how to communicate with martial artists.*

Comment: @JasonBassford I am afraid that I am not being able to clearly explain this to you. *"... how to communicate **with** martial artists"* does not work. Consider this example. John is a martial artist. John went to play basketball. Got into a scuffle over a hard foul. One player pushed John and started talking trash. Should John walk away? Talk trash? Choke him at will? Or should John knock him out? So basically this is about how John, who is a martial artist, should behave (or communicate) outside the dojo/gym with others who are not martial artists; the code of conduct for practitioners.

Comment: Fine. Then *…and martial-artist communication*. (Which works both ways, but still has to include at least one.)

Comment: Repetition is not always bad, sometimes it's the best wato eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My suggestion:

> Use this tag for questions about expected behavior, the correct code of conduct for different styles of martial arts, and communication among martial artists and with others.

Why say "interpersonal"? Who but persons are communicating?

Comment: Jack, "with others" makes a lot of sense. And yes, I don't know why "interpersonal" was there; I will remove it.

Comment: *Communication among martial artists* is fine. But the second half of the phrase parses to *communication with others*, which doesn't make much sense. (E.g., *communication among martial artists and communication with others.*) To be what you want it to be, it should read as *martial artists communicating amongst themselves and with others.* But that might still lack how a non–martial artist should initiate conversation with a martial artist …

Comment: @JasonBassford But we are not concerned with *"how a non-martial artist should initiate conversation with a martial artist"*. We are concerned with *"how a martial artist should initiate or have a conversation with a non-martial artist".

Comment: @JasonBassford I think the sense of the tag, in context, is "communications among us, and with others", where "us" is replaceable by martial artists.

Comment: @AIQ No, we are. Look at the comments under the question. It was specifically stated that this should also include how to (or how not to) approach a black belt if you are not one.

Comment: Instead of `among martial artists` could be `among their practitioners`.

Comment: @JasonBassford In that example, both are martial artists (white and black belts).

Comment: @AIQ So, you're saying that there should be no etiquette for a non-practitioner to speak to a practitioner?

Comment: @JasonBassford We (practitioners) can only lay down rules on how we should act. We can only tell those who are present in the gym/dojo/school how they should carry themselves inside and outside the gym/dojo/school. As a community, we have a code of conduct for our behaviour. We can control what we do, we can't control what others (non-practitioners) do.

Comment: @AIQ But that has nothing to do with answering the question—and it also contradicts itself. Either you tell others how to act or you don't. It's not clear what you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> Use this tag for questions about expected behavior, the correct code of conduct for different styles of martial arts, and interpersonal communication not only among martial artists but also between them and non-martial artists.

That removes one of the instances of the phrase martial artists while maintaining the overall meaning (I hope).

Comment: This is a much better phrasing. It at least seems to capture everything that's been communicated so far. (Although you could replace *non-martial artists* with just *others*, and it would parse more appropriately than the other answer.)

Comment: Wouldn't "non-martial artists" imply "artists that are not martial"? What are the grammatical rules for this?

Comment: @RobinHeller that is indeed the implication. I suppose one could have non martial-artists which would mean everything which is not a martial artist and so would include the Eiffel tower, the planet Mercury, a sparrow, a bottle of milk, and me but I imagine that would be rarely needed and almost pathological.